# VBA - Getting the complete row of one or more red highlighted cells from 3 specific columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a vba that would get the complete row of cell/s with red interior color. The table is consist of 9 columns situated from column B - J but dynamic in terms of rows.

I need to scan if the first row in column B is red then proceed to next row, else check Column h else column j. But the problem is, some values for column I were blank. what would be the correct coding for this?

I have this coding but it doesn't work 100%. But it cannot get the complete row when the red-filled cell was found in column J. Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Please show what you've got so far and a sample of what is working and what isn't

Comment: DP won't help here....

Comment: Hmm, I think you got downvoted because you pasted a screenshot when you can paste code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim checkCell As Object

    Set searchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("B1:J1")

    For Each checkCell In searchRange
        If checkCell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            MsgBox "i am red"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: downvoted? it does extactly what i understood that you need ^^